# How to pass parameters to Listener of TestNG, specific for each test?

Tags: java, automated-tests, listener, testng

Task: After completion each test method get specific parameters from each test method and pass in method, which should perform after completion each test. For example:

We have two tests:

```
@Listener(Listener.java)
public class UserManagementTests {

  public String descriptionForTest1 = "some description";
  public String descriptionForTest2 = "some description";
  public String successResult = "Test passed";

  @Test
  public void Test1(){
  ...
 }

  @Test
  public void Test2(){
  ...
 }
}
```

And class where located Listener:

```
public class Listener implements ITestListener {

 public void onTestSuccess(ITestResult result) {
        TlXml tlXml = new TlXml();
        tlXml.addThreadResult(result.getMethod().getMethodName(), true, testDescription, successResult);
        }
    }
}
```

I need after completion each test to pass in function `tlXml.addThreadResult` value of `descriptionForTest` and 'successResult' in parameter `testDescription` and `successResult` respectively.
OK, I know that description we can specify in

```
@Test(description = "Description")
```

and then get in Listener so

```
result.getMethod().getDescription()
```

But how pass not description parameters?

Comment: The description is not clear enough: What do you want, and why? Why don't you use @Test(description=) if you know it? BTW, if you want to generate your own report, a better listener exists: IReporter.

Comment: @juherr 3  Because I need passing not only description parameter. I need specific parameters for each test set in method 'tlXml.addThreadResult' after ending test.

Comment: It won't be an easy job. Could you tell me more about the use case? Are theses parameters static or dynamic depending on the test? Are they class or method dependent?